# PHP form name decomposition

Tags: php

Supposing that jQuery serialize form send data which is hard to decrypt :

`[someindex][0][anotherindex][0][] = 'value'`

In PHP, I need to decompose it into a real array, which is :

```
array(
   someindex => array(
      0 => array(
          anotherindex => array(
             0 => array('value')
          )
      )
   )
)
```

Is there a function that do this or how do I achieve this ?

EDIT:

Another word, If I have `$name = '[someindex][0][anotherindex][0][]'` as a PHP string, I want to create an array with the same structure

Sample : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d604f087aab07d48be27969e94dc9656fd90ffd
HTML client side : https://jsfiddle.net/bgay81q2/

JSON Data sent by client :

```
[{"name":"Data[index1][0][index2][0][]","value":"test"},{"name":"Data[index1][0][index2][0][]","value":"second value"}]
```

Comment: not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: PHP will do that automatically when it populates `$_POST` or `$_GET`

Comment: it is not PHP or normal form that is sending. JQuery serialize the form then send through Ajax name string as is

Comment: @SergChernata To make it simple, if you have `$name = '[someindex][0][anotherindex][0][]'` as a string; I need to create an array with the same structure

Comment: @Quentin I don't send form via html form but Ajax, and jquery doesn't structure the data correctly

Comment: @ThanhTrung — Under normal circumstance, jQuery will structure the data correctly. Try providing a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Fix it at source. Variable name cannot start from opening bracket. If your AJAX send a valid name, e.g. `var[someindex][0][anotherindex][0][] = 'value'`, *PHP will do that automatically when it populates `$_POST` (c) Quentin*

Comment: @Quentin Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/bgay81q2/1/ Try to open the console you'll understand

Comment: @ThanhTrung — "in the question itself", don't hide important bits of the question on a third party site.

Comment: @Quentin Not sure why you are trying to make my life harder but I already give lots of info, is it not enough?

Comment: @ThanhTrung do you want your question answered? If so, it's important to include all necessary infos in your question. If Quentin asked you these informations it's because it's needed.

Comment: @ThanhTrung — Not sure why you are trying to make the life of everyone willing to give you free help harder by refusing to follow the conventions of Stackoverflow and splitting your question over multiple websites.

Comment: I simply give examples by request. We can't just write php, html, js at the same time on the same page and has no ability to test it. So we need external site.

Comment: You can, there is the snippet widget specially for this in SO. And even without it, you don't need external websites to paste your code here indicating the different parts langages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are after is [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). There is an example how to use it with your JSON:

```
$str = '[
    {"name":"Data[index1][0][index2][0][]","value":"test"},
    {"name":"Data[index1][0][index2][0][]","value":"second value"}
]';

$input = json_decode($str);
// validate $input here
// then get the data:
parse_str(
    implode(
        '&',
        array_map(
            function($var){
                return urlencode($var->name) . '=' . urlencode($var->value);
            },
            $input
        )
    ),
    $request
);

print_r($request);
```

Comment: Great! This is what I'm looking for. Thousands thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking specifically about jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method, then PHP natviely supports this; the jQuery implementation generates a query fragment of a URL. So if this is appended to a GET request request URL or sent in the body of a POST, then the data will appear in PHP as $_GET ot $_POST (resp).

If you are smuggling the data back to PHP in some more esoteric way, then you can use PHP's [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert to an array.

Comment: In fact, it is a conversion that I need. Here is the sample http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d604f087aab07d48be27969e94dc9656fd90ffd